# (log n)^k = O(n)? For k greater 1

Tags: notation, logarithms

$$(\log n)^k = O(n)?$$ For $k> 1$.

$k$ is a constant, such as number $4$.

I think it is not true for $n=32$ and greater. $n=32, n=64, n=128,\dots$
So, I can not find $n_0$ and $c$.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way: use the definition of a limit and what easily follows from  l'Hopital's theorem:

$$ \lim \frac{\log^k n}{n} \to 0.$$

Comment: Excellent, you automatically get a proof by induction that $O(\log(n))^k<O(n)$ for all $k$.

Comment: Thanks. Can I want solve it? (Limit)

Comment: I find it. for n=2^32  => logarithm=(32)^4 that equal to 2^20. Now, 2^32 is greater than 2^20. Thanks every one. You Help me.